# Animating layout resize when keyboard open

Tags: android, animation, keyboard, android-animation, android-softkeyboard

I wonder if there is a way to animate the content of my layout when the keyboard is shown.

At the moment, when I launch my activity, it opens the keyboard, which is animated with a translation, but the rest of my view is just resized with a clunky and awful effect. I thought asking for `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` on my main layout would do the trick, but no. I guess because it only handles the layout changes inside of itself.

So is their any way to make my views translate/resize smoothly when the keyboard is shown/hidden?

PS: I don't want adjustPan, adjustResize is really what I need, I just want it to look better. Thx

Answer (score 15):

I realise you asked this question 9 months ago and no one answer it. I've only seen it for the first time now, probably you won't need it but I believe this might be a common issue.

What you need to do is to add, like you said, `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` . The trick here is the following:

- You add animateLayoutChanges in the parent layout of the editText
- You add the following code in your activity/view/fragment:

`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
   ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.your_root_layout_id);
   LayoutTransition layoutTransition = rootView.getLayoutTransition();    
   layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
  }`

Comment: i got this crash "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.animation.LayoutTransition.enableTransitionType(int)' on a null object reference", the root is FrameLayout